# How can I make my function refresh itself constantly?

Tags: android, xml, class, loops, layout

So I've been taking a look at how to do loops in Java using while methods, but they don't work for me. My Time functions is fairly simple but it doesn't update it self, so the time displayed on start would remain as is.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Time function
        TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
```

How exactly can I get my function to loop repeatedly, so there is no delay in time displaying. I've been trying many options but nothing seems to be working for me, I'm still learning v,v.

thanks if you help me out :)

EDIT - WHAT I DID

```
// Time function

final boolean keepRunning = true;
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){

        while(keepRunning){

            TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
            time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
                    time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: If one of the answers provided helped you solve your problem, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Updated my answer, you should be able to just copy and paste that and get it to work. And depending on how precise the time you're trying to show is (milliseconds is a bit over the top in normal cases), I really recommend toying around with the Thread.sleep I put in there. You could leave it out however, if necessary.

Comment: @SvenT23 Thank you so much, I just fixed up the small error by surrounding the Sleep bit by surround it with the try, catch function and it's working fine now :) Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I didn't have any running environment in front of me so things like that tend to slip my mind when writing code off the top of my head :) Glad to hear it helped, though

Comment: It's not a big deal, it worked :P Thanks again, I will use this method to refresh my other activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a thread, loop inside that thread. Use runOnUiThread to update your text value (can't be done in worker thread).

```
boolean keepRunning = true;
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){

        while(keepRunning){

            // make the thread wait half a second (if you're only showing time up to seconds, it doesn't need to be updating constantly)
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
                    time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

set keepRunning to false before exiting your app to stop the thread.

Comment: I changed the code to what I just added to the question, it doens't work. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything else than setting the textview's value to the current time, delete the 2 lines below the `while(keepRunning){`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Alright, so it doesn't crash the application anymore, instead it just shows a blank screen. Also it told me to change modifier of keeprunning to final and so I did.

Comment: Do you have this in your oncreate?

Answer (score 0):

From the [developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
```

}.start();

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Handler and use it to trigger this event:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

It has methods like to initiate an event in the future:

sendMessageAtTime(Message, long), and sendMessageDelayed(Message, long)

The Handler itself can not do a "repeated event", but you can just handle the Message in the Handler and resend a new future event via the same sendMessage method.